# Java - parse binary to long

Tags: java, string, binary, java-8

I have a binary represenation of a number and want to convert it to long (I have Java 8)

```
public class TestLongs {
public static void main(String[] args){
    String a = Long.toBinaryString(Long.parseLong("-1")); // 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(Long.parseLong(a, 2));// ??? but Long.parseUnsignedLong(a, 2) works
}
```

}

This code results in `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:592)`
What is wrong here? Why Long.parseLong(a, 2) doesn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Long.parseLong()` doesn't treat the first '1' character as a sign bit, so the number is parsed as 2^64-1, which is too large for `long`. `Long.parseLong()` expects input `String`s that represent negative numbers to start with '-'.

In order for `Long.parseLong(str,2)` To return `-1`, you should pass to it a `String` that start with '-' and ends with the binary representation of `1` - i.e. `Long.parseLong("-1",2)`.

Comment: then what is difference between Long.parseLong and Long.parseUnsignedLong? does "Unsigned" refer to binary represenation or long value??

Comment: @android_dev parseUnsignedLong expects to treat the long value as if it was unsigned.

Comment: `Long.parseUnsignedLong` treats the output `long` as an unsigned value, so when you treat a `long` value as unsigned, the max possible value becomes 2^64-1 (represented by 64 1 bits), which is why a String of 64 1s is acceptable. @android_dev

Comment: @PeterLawrey so, as you said, System.out.println(Long.parseUnsignedLong("1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111", 2)); should return positive number? but it return -1!

Comment: @android_dev parseUnsignedInt parses large unsigned values. `long` is still signed and no method changes that. You can treat as if it was unsigned of course.

Comment: @android_dev `long` is still signed, so when you print `Long.parseUnsignedLong("11111111111111111‌​11111111111111111111‌​11111111111111111111‌​1111111", 2))` you see -1. In order to see this number as an unsigned long, you need to print it with the static method `Long.toUnsignedString()`.

Comment: @android_dev Try - `System.out.println (Long.toUnsignedString (Long.parseUnsignedLong("1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111", 2)));`

Comment: @Eran Ok, thanks, already tried this! You are both right, but this part is so mixed in Java!

Comment: I thinked that it should parse as  two's complement binary code, that's whay i couldn't understand that!

Comment: @android_dev `parseLong(String s,int radix)` supports any radixes between 2 and 36, so it would be even more confusing for it to treat the String one way (two's complement) for radix 2 and another way for all other radixes. Therefore negative numbers are represented by the minus sign as the first character for all radixes.

Comment: @Eran yeah, i missed that! :)

Answer (score 3):

Eran is right, and the answer to your question is:

```
System.out.println(new BigInteger(a, 2).longValue());
```